# Getting contents of a webpage with python fails, instead returning a FortiADC Error page

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, shell, kubernetes

My Python code (which is on a Docker image, within an AWS EC2 box) is using the requests library to try and get the contents of a webpage. If I do something as simple as `requests.get(url='https://google.com', verify=False).text`, it will return the below, and of note is the "fortiadc_error_page".

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1013: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'google.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\t\n\t<head>\n\t</head>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<iframe src="/fortiadc_error_page/index.html" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="function resizeIframe(obj) {\n\t    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 10 + \'px\';\n\t  };resizeIframe(this)"></iframe>\n\t</body>
```

I remove the `verify` from the request, like so: `requests.get(url='https://google.com').text`, and I get back: `ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: ("hostname 'google.com' doesn't match either of '*.fortinet.com', 'fortinet.com'",)`

Anyone know how to fix these errors? I deployed this with a RHEL 8 AMI, so shouldn't be any special security things on here. And I've opened up ports to 443 and 80.

It is very strange as I could then do `requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com')` and that WORKS. but Google and CNN fail, and the website that I really want to pull from fails.

For a bit more detail - again I have an EC2 deployed on AWS, and on it I've installed K3D. On K3D I've installed a set of Kubernetes manifest files, which includes a cronjob. When I run that cronjob, it runs on a docker image, which has Python and runs the requests code, and fails.

Comment: It seems like something in your network path is incorrectly intercepting outgoing network traffic.  The `verify=False` tells the `requests` module "I'm okay talking to this fortinet thing and giving it my Google credentials"; you almost certainly do not want to set that.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things you have a dns issue. The container needs to be able to resolve external addresses correctly.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

```py
requests.get(url='https://google.com').text
```

Works perfectly otherwise.